# Unable to make changes in woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Unable to add spaces before the value of attribute in Woocoommerce Plugin enabling custom Attribute for Products, As Problem I am facing is that Value of Attribute is collapsing with the Table and I want to make it correct [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Rpg.png)

Code for products-attributes.php :

```
/**
 * Product attributes
 *
 * Used by list_attributes() in the products class.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Please help me out .......

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space in your `echo` like below:

```
<td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo ' ' . wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
```

or you can apply some left padding in your `td` element:

```
.woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Suggestions, but both of them didn`t work at all

Comment: @HassanMuhammadYounas is it possible to post here the URL of your site?